# residue $\frac{z}{(z-1)(z+1)^2}$ at $z = -1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

My attempt: $$f(z) = \frac{z}{(z-1)(z+1)^2} = \frac{1}{(z+1)^2}\cdot -z\frac{1}{1-z}$$ So at $D(-1;1)$ we have $$-z\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty-(z+1)^{k+1}$$ and this gives $$f(z) = \sum_{k=-1}^\infty-(z+1)^{k}.$$ So the residue at $z = -1$ is negative one but I feel like this is the wrong way of approaching this problem, because of the open disk I use. Also I think I proofed that $c_{-2} \neq 0$ because of a pole of order two here, so I'm not sure if this can be correct.

Comment: your calculations seem wrong to me, both the first line and the second

Comment: I edited the first line do you still think it is wrong?

Comment: Remember that the residue is only one coefficient. You could compute it without computing the whole series. $(z+1)^2f(z)$ is bounded near $z=-1$, while $(z+1)f(z)$ is not bounded near $z=-1$. Therefore, $f$ has a pole of order $2$ at $z=-1$. Since that is the case the residue can be computed by taking derivative of order **one** of $(z+1)^2f(z)$ and taking limit as $z\to=-1$. This is because we know that there should be an expansion of the form $f(z)=\frac{c_{-2}}{(z+1)^2}+\frac{c_{-1}}{z+1}+[\text{regular part}]$ and those operations produce $c_{-1}$ on the right.

Comment: No, though I would use parentheses to avoid $\times$ and $-$ close to the other

Comment: @owl if we write $(z+1)^2f(z) = c_2 + c_1(z+1) + \text{[regular part]}(z+1)^2$ and do the derivative, why do we need to put the limit and not just $z = 1$?

Comment: Well ... it is a technicality. You can say that the right hand side is an expression with a value for $z=-1$. However, strictly speaking, the left hand side has a division by $(z+1)$ and thus you shouldn't evaluate it at $z=-1$ unless you have defined what that division by zero means. In your case, the left hand side is a rational function. So, you will be able to "cancel" the $(z+1)^2$. This operation of "cancelling" is the act of replacing the left hand side with a new expression that is equivalent to the original, for $z\neq-1$.

Comment: In the new expression $\frac{z}{z-1}$ you could substitute $z=-1$ after taking the derivative.

Comment: @owl got it, thanks

Comment: The operation that is valid in all cases (of a pole) and that gives the same result is taking limit. It is a shorter explanation if you just say "take limit".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $z\in\Bbb C$ such that $|z+1|<2$, you have\begin{align}\frac z{z-1}&=1+\frac1{z-1}\\&=1-\frac1{2-(z+1)}\\&=1-\frac12\cdot\frac1{1-\frac{z+1}2}\\&=1-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z+1)^n}{2^{n+1}}\\&=\frac12-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(z+1)^n}{2^{n+1}}\end{align}and therefore, if $z\ne-1$,\begin{align}\frac z{(z-1)(z+1)^2}&=\frac1{2(z+1)^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(z+1)^{n-2}}{2^{n+1}}\\&=\frac1{2(z+1)^2}-\sum_{n=-1}^\infty\frac{(z+1)^n}{2^{n+3}}.\end{align}In particular,$$\operatorname{res}_{z=-1}\frac z{(z-1)(z+1)^2}=-\frac14.$$

Answer (score 2):

For a function with low and obvious pole degrees you can use the limit definition.

Recall the residue of an $n$ degree pole at $c$ of $f$ is $$\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to c}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}[(z-c)^nf(z)]$$

For your function $$\frac{z}{(z-1)(z+1)^2}$$ this has a simple pole at $1$ and a pole of order 2 at $-1$. Hence by the formula at $-1$ the residue is nothing but
$$\frac1{(2-1)!}\lim_{z\to -1}\frac{d}{dz}\left[{\color{red}{(z+1)^2}}\cdot \frac{z}{(z-1){\color{red}{(z+1)^2}}}\right]=\lim_{z\to-1} {-1\over(-1 + z)^2}=-\frac14$$

**Edit**: Ok i know that this has already been answered but w/e i'll still put my sereis answer here. We have $$\frac{z}{(z-1)(z+1)^2}={\color{blue}{(z+1)^{-2}}}\cdot \frac z{z-1}$$
Blue is already its own laurent series at $-1$, so we just need to find the series of the latter. Taylor expanding at -1 gives
$$(z+1)^{-2}\cdot \left( \frac12-\frac14 (z+1) - \frac18 (z+1)^2 - \frac1{16}(z+1)^3+... \right)$$
Notice that if we multiply it out, $(z+1)^{-2}\cdot -\frac14 (z+1)$ gives the negative one power term, implying the residue at that -1 is $-\frac14$.

Comment: This is a nice approach, but probably not the way I'm supposed to proof it because this theorem is the next excercise. Do you see another way?

Comment: @D.G.vandeSchepop Ah i see. If you have to do it the laurent series way i'll edit my answer later when I have time to revisit the question using it 

Comment: Would be great, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Set $z=-1+h.$ For $0<|h|<1,$
$$\begin{align}\frac z{(z-1)(z+1)^2}&=\frac{-1+h}{(-2+h)h^2}\\&=\frac{1-h}{2h^2(1-\frac h2)}\\&=\frac{1-h}{2h^2}\left(1+\frac h2+o(h)\right)\\&=\frac1{2h^2}\left(1-\frac h2+o(h)\right).
\end{align}$$
The residue of $\frac z{(z-1)(z+1)^2}$ at $z=-1$ is the coefficient of $\frac1h$ in this developement, i.e. $-\frac14.$